How to use pytorch to compute partial products of a matrix and a vector?
I want to implement a MoE model with fast speed and lower gpu memory use, and I'm facing trouble that can be abstracted in the following way:
Assume A[1:1024][1:1024] is a matrix, b[1:1024] is a vector, c[1:1024] is a sparse vector, with at most 100 nonzero elements. I need to compute d[1:1024] defined by d[i]=(A*b)[i] * c[i].
I need, for a fixed A, and many pairs (b,c), compute d. How should I compute d under pytorch, taking advantage of the parallel ability of cuda?
Taking right rows of A to form a new matrix? This can be fast, but uses a lot unnecessary gpu memory, and makes maximal possible batch size too small.
Using for loop to compute elements of d one by one on right indexes? This saves gpu memory, but too slow.
How to both save memory and be fast?
This cuda function could seems do the work. But I want to work inside pytorch, not cuda programming.
__global__ void computeDots(float *A, float *b, float *c, float *out, int *mask) {
    int idx = blockIdx.x * 100 + threadIdx.x;
    if (threadIdx.x < 100) {
        float *a = A + mask[idx] * VECTOR_SIZE;  
        for (int i = 0; i < VECTOR_SIZE; i++) {
            out[idx] += a[i] * b[idx+i];  
        }
        out[idx] *= c[idx];
    }
}

